# Rolling Mean By Group Dplyr/data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a large data.frame with 350k rows. Currently I am trying to create a rolling mean of the lag_close column in the data.table. Since
I am more fluent in `dplyr` than in `data.table` I tried to create a rolling mean using  `dplyr` which shot me an error.

```
df = df %>% na.omit()%>%  group_by(ticker) %>% mutate(avg10 = rollapplyr(lag_close, 10, mean))
```

> Error: Column `avg10` must be length 577 (the group size) or one, not
>   567

My next try was to go the data.table route as I saw people having success. 
No error is returned, but the output is very strange and not accurate.

```
df = as.data.table(df)
df[, laggedRets := rollapplyr(lag_close, 10, mean, na.rm = T), by = ticker]
tail(df, 10)
ticker ret.adjusted.prices ret.closing.prices lag_close         jump laggedRets
 1:   MELI         0.002731904        0.002731904    501.48  0.020174791    507.849
 2:   MELI         0.007258614        0.007258614    502.85  0.001966823    507.528
 3:   MELI        -0.002606134       -0.002606134    506.50 -0.011437339    507.085
 4:   MELI         0.018132218        0.018132218    505.18  0.003832865    506.282
 5:   MELI        -0.020628408       -0.020628408    514.34 -0.014373574    505.262
 6:   MELI         0.001568257        0.001568257    503.73  0.003428456         NA
 7:   MELI         0.018155879        0.018155879    504.52 -0.002957652         NA
 8:   MELI        -0.022815765       -0.022815765    513.68  0.002663470         NA
 9:   MELI        -0.007132015       -0.007132015    501.96 -0.005273231         NA
10:   MELI        -0.012801487       -0.012801487    498.38 -0.016467802         NA

head(df, 10)
  ticker ret.adjusted.prices ret.closing.prices lag_close         jump laggedRets
 1:     AA        0.0496011100       0.0496011100     28.83  0.006568736         NA
 2:     AA        0.0128883014       0.0128883014     30.26 -0.002647255         NA
 3:     AA        0.0009787928       0.0009787928     30.65  0.001304239         NA
 4:     AA       -0.0391134289      -0.0391134289     30.68  0.006497716         NA
 5:     AA        0.0508819539       0.0508819539     29.48  0.011802531     31.154
 6:     AA        0.0319560684       0.0319560684     30.98  0.003222691     31.752
 7:     AA        0.0334689407       0.0334689407     31.97  0.031709630     32.268
 8:     AA       -0.0009080811      -0.0009080811     33.04 -0.006680893     32.769
 9:     AA       -0.0112086950      -0.0112086950     33.01 -0.001212398     33.330
10:     AA        0.0664829064       0.0664829064     32.64  0.009452792     34.132
```

It seems like there are NA's on either side of the data.table, that should not be the case. Also the numbers are not accurate. I am not to sure what I am missing.
Here is a sample so you guys can test it out.

```
df =structure(list(ticker = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", 
"AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", 
"AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AABA", "AAL", "AAL", 
"AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", 
"AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", 
"AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", 
"AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", 
"AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAOI", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", 
"ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", 
"ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV", "ABBV"), lag_close = c(28.83, 30.26, 
30.65, 30.68, 29.48, 30.98, 31.969999, 33.040001, 33.009998, 
32.639999, 34.810001, 35.419998, 35.66, 36.290001, 37.5, 36.529999, 
36.299999, 36.669998, 36.549999, 36.450001, 38.900002, 40.060001, 
41.34, 41.23, 41.34, 42.299999, 42.59, 42.110001, 42.27, 41.990002, 
42.029999, 42.09, 42.049999, 42.400002, 43.900002, 44.939999, 
44.549999, 44.419998, 43.93, 44.07, 46.299999, 46.700001, 45.889999, 
46.209999, 47.080002, 48.48, 48.639999, 48.099998, 47.650002, 
46.75, 47.639999, 47.259998, 48, 46.939999, 47.540001, 47.91, 
49.59, 46.950001, 44.900002, 44.25, 23.1, 23.51, 22.809999, 22.42, 
22.24, 22.870001, 22.719999, 29.860001, 28.219999, 30.440001, 
30.84, 30.48, 30.58, 31.290001, 32, 31.709999, 31.280001, 31.15, 
30.41, 30.76, 116.150002, 116.019997, 116.610001, 117.910004, 
118.989998, 119.110001, 119.75, 119.25, 119.040001, 120, 119.989998, 
119.779999, 120, 120.080002, 119.970001, 121.879997, 121.940002, 
121.949997, 121.629997, 121.349998, 62.41, 63.290001, 63.77, 
63.790001, 64.209999, 64.07, 61.139999, 61.279999, 61.990002, 
61.860001, 61.66, 61.380001, 61.150002, 60.959999, 60.580002, 
61.380001, 61.27, 60, 60.43, 61.110001)), row.names = c(NA, -120L
), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ticker", "lag_close"))
```

Comment: `data.table` recently gained `frollmean` function

Comment: brilliant. Worked great. Thanks

Comment: do you need `df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(avg10 = rollmeanr(lag_close, 10, na.pad = TRUE))` ? or `df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(avg10 = rollmeanr(lag_close, 10, fill = TRUE))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `map` from the `purrr` package and apply it on `1:n()`:

```
df = df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(ticker) %>% 
  mutate(avg10 = map_dbl(1:n(), ~mean(lag_close[(max(.x-9, 1)):.x], na.rm =T))
```

Of course you have to decide what should happen with the first 9 rows where there are fewer than 10 observations. In my solution the rows 1 to 9 contain the mean of the last 1 to 9 observations.

Comment: Hi, Cett. I am getting an error here. Error in lag_close[(min(.x - 9, 1)):.x] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: Sorry, you have to take `max` instead of `min`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot Cett! Have a great weekend

Answer (score 3):

Here's the `data.table()` approach with rows 1-9 being NA.

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, laggedRets := frollmean(lag_close, 10, na.rm = T), by = ticker]
```

Also, it was unclear whether the `NA` should be removed before the rolling mean. If that's the case, you would use:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[!is.na(lag_close), laggedRets := frollmean(lag_close, 10), by = ticker]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently figured out a way you can perform 1 single rolling mean calculation even for an arbitrary number of groups using `data.table`.

The `frollmean` has an `adaptive` argument that lets you supply a vector of window sizes, (provided you align "right").

This means if your data are sorted by the groups, you simply need to give it the correct window vector.

```
setorder(dt, ticker)
group_sizes <- dt[, .N, by = ticker]$N
window_size <- 10L
window <- pmin(sequence(group_sizes), window_size)
window[window < window_size] <- NA_integer_

library(bench)
mark(e1 = dt[, laggedRets := frollmean(lag_close, 10, na.rm = TRUE), by = ticker]$laggedRets,
     e2 = dt[, laggedRets := frollmean(lag_close, n = window, na.rm = TRUE, 
                                       adaptive = TRUE)]$laggedRets)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 e1            512us  601us     1471.   131.1KB     4.35   676     2      460ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 e2            308us  378us     2411.    50.6KB     4.37  1103     2      458ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

I have a function `roll_mean()` in my package timeplyr which does this and accepts unsorted data too.

Link: https://github.com/NicChr/timeplyr

### Benchmark with lots of groups

```
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
dt <- data.table(g = sample.int(1e05, 1e06, TRUE),
                 x = rnorm(10^6))
mark(e1 = dt[, mean := roll_mean(x, n = 7, g = get("g"), partial = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)]$mean,
     e2 = dt[, mean := frollmean(x, n = 7, align = "right", na.rm = FALSE), by = "g"]$mean)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
1 e1         57.28ms 73.11ms    14.0     58.75MB     0        7     0   500.99ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 e2           4.04s   4.04s     0.248    1.54GB     1.98     1     8      4.04s <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

We can see that setting up the correct window vector results in a ~60x speedup and a ~25x memory reduction.